# How to format numbers in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, google-sheets-formula

I have a lot of code for Google Sheets and now I start to use it in NativeScript. I know how to format numbers in Google Sheets but I didn’t find any similar options in  component.

For example, my function return percent value, it is the number between 0 and 1. In Google Sheets I write code =myFunction(), then I select appropriate format for cell and it looks like 23.5%.

In NativeScript I’m using XML file and write

```
<Label text=“{{ myFunction }}”/>
```

But it shows 0.2358765 and I don’t find any options in NativeScript documentation how to properly format this number.

I’m not familiar with CSS, may be I have to use CSS? What command of CSS or NativeScript I have to use to format the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare [Converters](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#using-converters-in-bindings) either in your data model or in application module if you like to reuse the same often.

What you write in your converter totally depends on how you want to format your numbers. There are even NPM packages those support interpreting Excel Formulas, you might want to check them too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

`<Label text=“{{ (myVariable).toLocaleString('en-us', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) }}”/>`

These links will give you more details and a few different alternatives:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat
- https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#using-converters-in-bindings

Comment: (myVariable).toLocaleString('en-us', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}) - is not supported in NativeScript, but thanks for the links I have chek them out.